# Maven - Artifcat Descriptor Exception - Local Repository and Online Conflict

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml

So, I have a bit of a problem and being a bit new to Maven am not sure how to procede.

I have a Maven Project with a bunch of dependencies.  Most of them are the typical stuff like Jackson, Mongo, Junit, etc.  However, I also have dependencies on some local requirements that I have.

In eclipse I went File->Import->Install Or Deploay an Artifact to a Maven Repo

I point to the proper artifact and it's coresponding pom file and all is well.  the pom.xml file doesn't throw any errors and all is good.  However, if I go to the overview or look at the code in general it's not picking up these libraries.

I went and verified in my .m2\repository folder and all the libraries are there.  I used 7zip and the code is in the jars as I'd except.

So, I thought - I'll try to do a Maven Update and have it be done in Offline mode to tell it to look at the local repos.  Well, if I do that - the following error occurs:

UnresolvableModelException: Cannot access central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact has not been downloaded from it before.

If I then go back and try to do a regular update I get the following

ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for XXXX:YYYY  which is my local repository stuff.

Seems I lose either one or the other.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Try to run Maven in debug mode with -X option, then past it here.  $M2_HOME or localrepository could be wrong (due to settings.xml not configured or overriden by another one).

Comment: One was being over-written - post that as a answer so I can mod you up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run Maven in debug mode with -X option :

```
mvn install -X
```

You should see more information :

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from D:\tools\apache-maven-3.2.1\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\jrrevy\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at D:\tools\apache-maven-3.0.5\.m2\repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for D:\tools\apache-maven-3.0.5\.m2\repository
```

$M2_HOME or localrepository could be wrong due to settings.xml not configured or overriden by another one. This often happen, even to me.